# "one bottle (of) water"

Tags: grammar, prepositions, abbreviations, contractions

I've seen a photo of a sign, from a site that I believe is a hiking route in the US, warning about extreme heat. It reads

```
    WARNING!
  Extreme heat

Minimum 1 bottle
water per person

   No sandals
    Wear hat
```

Is using "one bottle water" instead of "one bottle **of** water" a common abbreviation in contexts like road signs?

Is "bottle" being used as an unit of measurement? I'm thinking of an usage such as "1 kg apples" (without "of") that is – I believe – the standard writing for "one kilogram of apples" (with "of") in contexts such as recipes.

Comment: The minimalist use of words is likely for expediency on the sign and to make the words as large and legible as possible. It's not really a grammatical application as these are not sentences. The message is still conveyed here, and it is common for signs to be abbreviated to the point of misunderstanding!

Comment: @Manhatton  +1 - it's for expediency.  It also says "Wear hat", not "Wear a hat".

Comment: It's in [Headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese).

Comment: Yes, I assumed that the reason was practicality. I asked mainly to know whether there are common traits to those kinds of abbreviations. I don't question that the sign is acceptable (even though the friend who posted that photo online was being particularly upset about that sign)

Comment: My previous comment was written before reading @ColinFine's, which answers my question about the common traits.

Comment: Vital though that clearly is in its own context, signage has prolly less and certainly no more use for rules of English than, for instance, lists do… which is to say, almost none.

Answer (score -1):

The most expedient answer would be to reverse the order of the compound noun, thereby keeping the same number of words but *also* having it be grammatical:

> Minimum 1 water bottle per person.

In fact, that's what I normally *do* see on signs such as these that use "headline-esque" phrasing. It seems that this particular sign went with something nonstandard.

---

Perhaps to add to your friend's wrath at the sign, I should also point out that going barefoot satisfies the condition of "no sandals," something which I'm sure they would not want you to do, so there's a semantic issue there too . . .

Comment: Water bottle doesn't have the same meaning than bottle of water, the way they taught me.

Comment: A water bottle can be empty, "bottle water" emphasises that you must bring water, not just receptables.